# Performing strstr on an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, offset

I managed to do this before somehow and have forgotten how to do it.  I keep getting an undefined offset notification for element associations (e.g. where $arr[$i] => "something").  E.g. for the following:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {

  if($a = strstr($arr[$i], "str"))
  {
    print "Found: ". $a. "<br>";
  }
  else {

    if($i >= count($arr))
    {
      print "Couldn't find <i>str</i>.<br>";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

That won't work and will output an undefined offset notification.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if($i >= count($arr)) will never be true because of the $i<count($arr) in your if-statement

Comment: @user1027167 how is that true? $i increments with every iteration of the for loop < the length of $arr, so if $arr contains 5 elements, then check if $i >= 5, and then throw some output.

Comment: the condition $i<count($arr) is checked after $i is incremented. why don't you test it:  
    $arr = array('A', 'B');
    for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
     if($i >= count($arr))
      echo 'dada!';    
    echo 'end';

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate trough array with [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), not with `for`. Your code should look like this:

```
foreach( $arr as $item){
    if(($a = strstr($item, "str")) !== false){
        print "Found: ". $a. "<br>";
    }
}
```

[`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) may return `''` when it matches on last character, therefor use `!== false`

> Returns the portion of string, or FALSE if needle is not found.

#### Doing it with `for` anyway

You have to be able to handle associative arrays as well:

```
$arr = (
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val2',
   ...
);
```

Than you'd have to use code like this:

```
$keys = array_keys( $arr);
$count = count( $keys);
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $item = $arr[ $keys[$i]];
}
```

Use `foreach` instead .)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work but only for elements that are represented by a superficial element (e.g. array("abcdefgh"=>"hello world"), it won't work for "abcdefgh" but I can search the element that's associated with it).

Comment: Apologies for the bump, but if I were to use a for loop, how would I test to see if the current selected element is an array key? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
  if($a = strstr($arr[$i], "str")) {
    print "Found: ". $a. "<br>";
  } else {
    if($i >= count($arr)) {
      print "Couldn't find <i>str</i>.<br>";
      return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

First if function was missing a bracket.

Comment: In this case `if($i >= count($arr)) {` is equal to condition `if(0){` and whole `else{}` part is therefore empty, you have 5 totally useless lines of code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added the bracket you were missing in second line and it works for me

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
  if($a = strstr($arr[$i], "str")) {
    print "Found: ". $a. "<br>";
  } else {
    if($i >= count($arr)) {
      print "Couldn't find <i>str</i>.<br>";
      return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: That was just a typo for the post, sorry.  It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you say something like this?

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(strstr($value, $a)) {
        print "Found: ". $a . "<br />";
    }
}
```

For the print you want to show, I imagine that the $a is what you're looking for in this array.